# sending dynamic data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have form and you can you're employment history to it, this is displayed in a row of three inputs: Job title, Job duration and job location. you can add employment which adds an empty set of inputs, in which you can add more data.

I'm sending the HTML form to a PHP script via AJAX, it is sending all the sets of inputs with the same name separately, so not in an array. on the PHP side, I'm json encoding the post variables by putting them in an array. `$json_data`

The issue is that the PHP script saves only the last set of inputs. so if you enter 3 jobs it only saves the last one.

```
<!-- employment row -->

    <p class="mt-3 text-left"> Employment history </p>
    <div class="row employment_block">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="job_title[]" placeholder="Job title">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="job_duration[]" placeholder="Duration (i.e. 3 months / 1 year)">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="job_location[]" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
        <button href="#" class="able_btn m-0 w-100 disabled" disabled aria-disabled="true" style="opacity:0.5"> remove </button>
        </div>

    </div>

        <div class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">
            <a class="add_employment" href=""> Add employment </a>  
        </div>



<!-- JS --> 

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".account_cv_update_form").submit(function(evt){  
evt.preventDefault();

      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
   $.ajax({
       url: 'handlers/cv_update.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData,
       async: false,
       cache:false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {

      switch(response.message){   
        case 'success': success();
        break;
        case 'error': error();
        break;

      }

    }
  });
return false;
});

});



$('.add_employment').click(function(evt) {
 evt.preventDefault();

    $('.employment_block:last').after('<div class="row employment_block"><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_title" placeholder="Job title"></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_duration" placeholder="Duration (i.e. 3 months / 1 year)"></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_location" placeholder="Country"></div><div class="col-md-3 text-center"><button class="able_btn m-0 w-100 remove_employment"> remove </button></div></div>');
});



<!-- PHP code --> 

$json_data = array(
        'job_title' => $job_title,
        'job_location' => $job_location,
        'job_duration' => $job_duration );


$cv_data = json_encode($json_data);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE  table SET profile_picute=:profile_picute, first_name=:first_name, last_name=:last_name, phone_number=:phone_number, email_address=:email_address, data=:data WHERE id=:id");

     $stmt->bindParam(':profile_picute', $new_file_name);
     $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
     $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
     $stmt->bindParam(':phone_number', $phone_number);
     $stmt->bindParam(':email_address', $email_address);
     $stmt->bindParam(':data', $cv_data);
     $stmt->bindParam(':id', $user_id);


if($stmt->execute()){
$response["message"] = 'success';   
}else{
$response["message"] = 'error'; 
$errors++;
}

echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```

Comment: *"// save $cv_data to mysql in here."* - How do we know if the php/mysql is correct? I think this goes deeper than shown.

Comment: I don't know JS that much, but the inputs in `$('.employment_block:last').after.....` do not have arrays `[]` as you have for the inputs above that, so I'm not sure if they should have them also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- coz it's going into mysql...

Comment: yeah i know that. But how are we to know if your php/mysql is written properly? I'll have to sit this one out, sorry.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good point, I've updated the question.

Comment: Best I can offer, are links for error checking. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and to look at your developer console. I hope this helps.

Comment: and what about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455781/sending-dynamic-data-to-php?noredirect=1#comment81866094_47455781) that I wrote earlier?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it. you were right. create an answer and i'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments area:

> I don't know JS that much, but the inputs in `$('.employment_block:last').after.....` do not have arrays `[]` as you have for the inputs above that, so I'm not sure if they should have them also.

The OP:

> Yes, I just checked it. you were right. create an answer and i'll mark it correct. – bob

So I was right and I've learned some JS today ;-)

Therefore this line:

```
$('.employment_block:last').after('<div class="row employment_block"><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_title" placeholder="Job title"></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_duration" placeholder="Duration (i.e. 3 months / 1 year)"></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_location" placeholder="Country"></div><div class="col-md-3 text-center"><button class="able_btn m-0 w-100 remove_employment"> remove </button></div></div>');
});
```

Should read as and adding `[]` for the inputs:

```
$('.employment_block:last').after('<div class="row employment_block"><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_title[]" placeholder="Job title"></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_duration[]" placeholder="Duration (i.e. 3 months / 1 year)"></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="job_location[]" placeholder="Country"></div><div class="col-md-3 text-center"><button class="able_btn m-0 w-100 remove_employment"> remove </button></div></div>');
});
```

In order to treat them as arrays.

Comment: Thanks for that, must have over looked it.